# What sensory mechanism allows a person to "see" based on the different density levels of physical matter?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, brain, senses, vision

Scenario 1:
A person is dozing for short time with the light on, likely only a few minutes, and upon gradual return to his/her normal "eye vision only" consciousness, briefly "sees" the brick outlines of the cement wall BEHIND the painted drywall of the far wall.  At first, the outlines of the brick seem to be being drawn in, similar to watching writing appear on the wall, then vision solidifies into whole wall being recognizable as brick wall pattern. This lasts only seconds until full normal vision/awareness returns.

Scenario 2:
Again upon awakening from a full night of sleep, a person is beginning to be aware of being awake, and has not yet opened their eyes. While eyes are CLOSED, the person "sees" the corner of the room they are facing where the ceiling meets the walls. The vision lacks color and resembles more different shades of light and dark appearing in the shape of the corner. As soon as the person concentrates on this unusual occurence and tries to analyze what is occurring, the vision disappears. During this vision, the person also feels an intensity of feeling in the middle of the forehead just above the eyes, as if  that spot were being touched by  something that is very slightly vibrating.

Scenario 3:
The person awakens in the night after unknown length of time sleeping and with eyes CLOSED, watches, in a dark room with no lights on, a darker shaded human shape walk past the bottom edge of the bed. The person is awake enough to be consciously aware of this, but falls immediately back to sleep, and recalls it clearly in the morning.

Scenario 4:
Upon waking up from dozing on a couch, the person looks towards an electric fireplace that is radiating heat. This time with eyes open, the person sees the heat waves radiating out of the fireplace towards them, almost exactly like the effect when a person observes heat waves on a hot summer day pavement. This lasts only a few seconds until the person is fully awake and wondering how they could have seen what they just saw. This scenario is different than the others since it seems to be the heat waves themselves that is being perceived, and not a solid object.

In all scenarios, dreaming is ruled out by the person due to lack of "non-real" elements and simple recognition of the occurrence as not a dream.

I'm looking for answers to explain seeing physical objects/heat waves these ways. The person is trying to make sense of things and see if they can figure out what is happening biologically to cause these different kinds of perception during between wake and sleep transitions.

What type of brainwave is in use during this kind of sensing?  I am assuming this sensing is connected to a specific type of brain wave due to the vision only occurs during a change in conscious awareness from sleep to awake. Is that a valid assumption? It is not yet known if other kinds of awareness states such as those achieved during meditation will allow this kind of "vision".

What areas of the brain would be in use during this type of sensing besides the occipital lobe?

Can a spatial recognition kind of sense be involved and somehow connected to vision sense?

Memory-created vision considered as a possibility,  but doesn't seem to be the answer due to the person having never seen the brick wall behind the drywall.

Although related and considered, the subject of synesthesia does not seem to provide an explanation for this kind of sensing due only vision involved (as far as commonly known senses go,  anyway).

Edits:
Sound is not involved in any of these scenarios. In fact, the person is actually moderately hearing impaired, largely corrected by hearing aids.

The new sensory experiences began to occur after significant spiritual growth and existential reflection by the person, and this fact very possibly is connected to and somehow paving the way for a new sense to activate.

Comment: Some of these questions such as "which part of the brain might be used" or "is this connected to vision" really need an implementation before we answer it.  For example, if this ability is based on acoustic techniques such as echolocation, one would expect the auditory centers to be involved.

Comment: Sound is not involved. Echolocation was also considered, but in the sense that there might be a different kind of wave that it's being sensed than sound. Does that exist? There is no implementation yet. The person is trying to figure out what is happening based on the events happening to them described above. I will edit to add another piece of the puzzle for scenario 2 that may also have bearing, and also a 4th scenario. Unfortunately the 4th scenario complicates things by the  sense  under investigation perceiving changes in the air itself based on temperature, and not physical matter.

Comment: «I am assuming this sensing is connected to a specific type of brain wave» I don’t think you understand what [brainwaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) are, or this is a bad translation.

Comment: My understanding of brain waves includes that there are different types of waves found predominantly during different states of consciousness, such as fully awake, dozing, REM sleep. Alpha, theta, etc.

Comment: I reviewed the help topics and info on the type of world building to ask questions about, and decided my questions do not quite belong here. You could say that character building may be more appropriate. (Because we are discovering new things so quickly now, I was asking in case someone would recognize what sense this is and share what it is called and where to find what others are learning about it.) Should I remove/delete the question?

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you’re asking on the right forum.  Your wording and subsequent comments makes it appear that this is a real thing that you want help understanding.

Since the eyes are closed, it would require ESP (that is, magic) or some kind of implanted technology. Maybe he’s a cyborg sleeper agent unaware of his own nature, but unconciously accesses other senses at times.

For real-world perceptions, [hypnagogic halucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia#Sights) are the opposite (that is, when falling asleep). the waking-up version is called *hypnopompic*.

> Hypnagogic phenomena may be interpreted as visions, prophecies, premonitions, apparitions and inspiration (artistic or divine), depending on the experiencers' beliefs and those of their culture.

Comment: JDlugosz, you might be right. Is there another forum you recommend?  In my understanding,   building of a new or different world occurs whenever there has been an extreme change in someone's perception of what their reality actually is. This question is set in the first years after that epiphany (a bit dramatic sounding, but still applicable word) has occurred, and the person is working to build their new reality by examining the nature of the new different perceptions they observe with an attempt to be objective about it rather than use their opinions created during their original reality.

Comment: I've read before about hypnagogic phenomena and the topic describes generically types of experiences similar to the scenarios I ask about, but do not find descriptions or a name for the specific sensing I lay out in the question.

Comment: Again I’m confused with your phrase «in my understanding…» because I expect instead “in the story I’m plotting…”  and «building a new world occurs…» makes me think you are using the term to mean something vastly different.  There’s no Psycology Stack Exchange.

Comment: This may not be the right place to post as I'm not understanding the forum rules I think. Most of the questions I have read so far the author writes them with expectation the audience here assumes it is a story without stating that, so I tried to do the same. I misunderstood the correct world building usage, but still got useful information in the answers.

Comment: Feel free to ask usage questions in [meta], or have more informal discussion in [chat].  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Without a specific mechanism defined, most of your questions lack a specific answer.  We are just begining to unlock the mysteries of the brain with science, and what we do know is based on reality, not a fictional ESP

However, we can make some guesses about brain activity based on the kind of processing the ESP calls for.  The brain's most powerful capacity is its ability to do pattern matching.  The different centers of the brain specialize in different sorts of pattern matching, so the brain would likely reuse existing circuitry if it could.

If your ESP signals come across as a set of frequencies and phases, the auditory regions will likely get involved.  If things like edge detection are called for, the visual centers of our brain are primed for that.  If it calls for continuous smooth interaction with some palpable force, our sense of touch, with its close entwined relationships with the motor centers would be a natural fit.

Comment: Maybe I should add the reality check tag. Your answer indicates this kind of sensory functioning is not real, which is one thing I'm tryimg to determine-if it exists in reality, what is this sense or sensory organ/brain function called-I just don't know the name of it, but that could be because it doesn't exist, which is not the answer I'm hoping for. I'll add that there's a lot of spirituality and soul-growth connected to this person as these experiences did not begin until after profound spiritual understanding occured. That topic doesn't seem to belong to world building here?

Comment: Adding a spiritual element would certainly help.  Science certainly does not recognize the kind of sensory experiences you describe.  It would be considered to be ESP.  There's no scientific evidence for ESP, despite a great deal of effort to find such evidence.  That doesn't mean it *can't* exist, but it does mean that you're going to have a hard time developing a purely scientific explanation for it.  The nice thing about my answer is that it will apply, even if the sensory functioning is spiritual... the brain is likely to still undergo pattern matching.

Comment: It lets you hand-wave away the actual reason for the ESP, while permitting you to have enough scientifically framed content to keep any scientists in your book busily probing the brain for clues.  It also gives you the opportunity to use synthestesia to explain a great deal of what is going on (in terms of experiences and qualia) without forcing you to claim that synethtesia actually explains how the perception happens in the first place.

Comment: I like the idea of pattern matching and will see if that topic can have relevance. One problem I have is this: what scientific evidence is there for vision, hearing, touch, taste and smell other than many people can describe it as occurring? Since the very nature of a sense is a personal one, how do you prove it to someone else? If  the person can find another person or group of people who similarly describe their perceptions, might that be considered proof of the existence of an ESP? Many have named & described other types of ESP for hundreds of years, and they are still not considered real.

Comment: «how do you prove it to someone else?» the JREF specializes in devising scientific tests for that. If you are getting useful information via abnormal means, it can be verified in principle. If it’s not something that can be verified objectivity, there’s no reason for saying it wasn’t just a dream you invented.

Comment: @N2ition Have you heard of "[qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia)?"  It is the philosophical term used to describe this concept of sensation being personal.  You may benefit from the massive body of content that has been put forth around the topic.  That being said, JDlugosz is right.  If you want *scientific* proof, as opposed to any other source of justification, your ESP must be objective, and once it is objective it can be tested.  That's just the rules of science.  It so happens that, in the current world, science is highly trusted.

Comment: @JDługosz, although I am definitely not a skeptic while researching, I have a healthy amount of respect for the scientific method. At a glance, the JREF forum has a different level of respectful commentary than I have seen here, but it may prove useful for researching ideas.

Comment: @Cort Ammon, I did not know the term qualia and will look at that closer. After quick review, it's a good explanation of what I am trying to describe in the scenarios. The fact that there is even conflict about the very definition of what the word qualia means tells me a lot about the difficulty others have had with objective description of sensory perceptions.